# Response variable in java implementation of xgBoost?

Tags: java, machine-learning, xgboost, training-data

Example from https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/java_intro.html says that you train your model with:

`Booster booster = XGBoost.train(trainMat, params, nround, watches, null, null);`

But I cannot understand where is your y_train (response / explained variable) used? trainMat containes variables that explain the response (X_train), but from where model even knows the correct values it should learn from?

In python implementation, we have .fit() for that:
`xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)` where we give both explaining and explained values.

How give response values to xgBoost training in java? Should it be in DMatrix?

Comment: The link you have provided indicates that it has to be DMatirx indeed, which in general contains the labels, too; the equivalent option in the Python API is not `fit` but `train`: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html#training

Comment: @desertnaut what are dmatrix's labels in your opinion? Are they "y" i'm looking for?